# Decompile in Radare for use in AVR studio, byte addressing vs word addressing

Tags: radare2

Hoping this has a simple answer...

I'm trying to use Radare2 to generate assembly code that later can be compiled in Avr studio 7. What I notice is that Radare (running pD) generates assembly code that is byte addressed whereas Avr Studio works with word addressing. 
Is there any simple way of instructing Radare2 to handle addressing using words rather than bytes?
Many thanks in advance!

Regards,
  Staffan

Comment: Have you seen this question? - https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/14556/can-radare2-support-word-oriented-architectures

Comment: Yes, but that seems more like a developer question. I’m looking for some way of configuring Radare.